# Need Jquery to switch between 3 servlet pages

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I need Jquery and the corresponding js and css files to switch between the servlet files.

For example: I am having 3 servlets Myservlet1.java, myservlet2.jave & myservlet3.java each displaying a table value. I need Jquery to switch betweent the servlets like myservlet displaying for 20 secs and then myservlet2 displays for 20 secs then myservlet3 displays for 20 sec.

The switch should be automatic. I am entirely new to Jquery and I badly need the code immediately ASAP.

Thanks in advance!!

I am displaying the results of 3 tables in corresponding java files. in the page values of tables will be displayed in servlets. Now I need to switch the servlets for every 1 min so that the record of 3 tables will be displayed in the specific interval of time

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this fairly simply with an array of urls, a current index, and an ajax call in a recursively-called setTimeout.

Comment: I would not call the functions recursively - although it's quite elegant - it will finally eat all your stack. My idea is almost the same an array of urls from which you can fetch data via ajax, a a counter incremented modulo 3 in order to switch between servlets and a function called with setInterval which does the fetch job from the ith value of url array.

Comment: @DanielVoina maybe recursively was the wrong word. But `function myFunction() { setTimeout(function() { myFunction(); }, 1); }` doesn't increase the size of the callstack. Using setInterval would depend on the behavior you wanted.. if the ajax call itself takes a significant amount of time and the interval is low enough, you could have issues.

Comment: @JasonP: it is clearer now what you wanted to say. Yes, you're right, in case of a longer AJAX call setInterval might have some issues - i mentioned it as a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery `load`-function with callbacks, and perform a `setTimeout` for each callback. The code would look something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
var delayTime = 20 * 1000;

// Wait on servlet 1
setTimeout(function() {
    $( "#content" ).load( "myservlet2.java", function() {
        // Wait on servlet 2        
        setTimeout(function() {
            $( "#content" ).load( "myservlet3.java", function() {
                // Servlet 3 loaded
            });
        }, delayTime);
    }); 
 }, delayTime);
```

This would load the page inside a HTML-element with id `content`. However, it doesn't seem like a good approach. Maybe you could explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am displaying the results of 3 tables in corresponding java files. So the page refreshes every 10 min interval so the updated values will be displayed in servlets. Now I need to switch the servlets for every 1 min so that the last 10 min record of 3 tables will be displayed

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java servelets so I might have misunderstood you, but as I understand it you want data from three different tables shown on a single webpage with 10 min intervals before each refresh? You should probably load all three at once, distribute the return values across the webpage in those tables and do it again after 10 minutes.